# Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, audio-recording

[enter image description here](https://ibb.co/TmJpHXM)I am trying to make an app for recording voice and change it but when I'm trying to run my code its crashed inline "audioRecorder.stop()".

Here is my code

```
@IBAction func StopBT(_ sender: Any) {


RecordingBT.isEnabled = true

StopRecordingBT.isEnabled = false


recordingLable.text = "Tap to recording"


audioRecorder.stop()
let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
try! audioSession.setActive(false)


}
```

Comment: Add crash log or the reason for crash.

Comment: try! audioSession.setActive(false). We should avoid force unwrapping.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
try! audioSession.setActive(false)
```

with

```
do {
  try audioSession.setActive(false)
 } catch {
print(error.localizedDesrciption) }
```

Comment: Is audioRecorder initialized?

Comment: Is the audioRecorder getting initialized?

Comment: Where did you initialize audioRecorder ?